# TABTIP.EXE - The exception unknown software exception (0xc0000420) occurred in the application at location 0xd8d84148

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have the following error in windows server 2012 r2 installation and i am wondering if anyone can help.

---

### Text and Image of Error Message:

[Server 2012 R2 installation error after product key " TABTIP.EXE - The exception unknown software exception (0xc0000420) occurred in the application at location 0xd8d84148. Click OK to Terminate The Program."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxTpw.jpg)

### What was I doing when I received the error?

The error occurred while attempting to install Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 on a system.

### Operating System:

Windows Server 2012 r2 x64

### SYSTEM SPECS:

```
|   Component   | Dell Reference Number |                                Details                                |
|---------------|-----------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------------|
| LAN           | 224-6716              | Intel Gbps 10/100/1000 network adapter                                |
| WPAN          | 430-0700              | Dell Wireless 370 Bluetooth Mo dule (2.1+EDR)                         |
| WLAN          | 430-0737              | Intel WiFi Link 5300 802.11AGN Half Mini Card                         |
| Battery       | 312-0950              | 9-cell Battery                                                        |
| CPU           | 317-2361              | Intel Core i7 720QM 1.6GHz (2. 8 GHz Turbo Mode, 6MB Cache)           |
| RAM           | N/A                   | 16GB, DDR3, 1600MHz 2 Dimm                                            |
| GPU           | 320-1307              | ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5730 - 1GB                                     |
| Hard Drive    | N/A                   | Intel 240 GB SSD                                                      |
| Display       | 320-8330              | 15.6 inch Wide Screen 16:9 1080p Full HD WLED LCD, W/2.0 MP, XPS 1645 |
| Optical Drive | 313-8874              | 8X DVD+/-RW Slot Load Drive                                         |
```

### Notes:

- The error comes up right after entering the product key for the installation.

  - It makes no difference whether I use a Standard, Essentials, Core, Datacenter etc key.
- After this error the system resets, except for two or three times, it allows me to continue, and then proceeds to freeze up.
- I have tried other installation media
- I have tried doing a network install.

---

If you need any other information please ask.  I have searched all over the place and found nothing useful so any information that you have is greatly helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not many things that can cause this problem:
1.) Bad installation medium
2.) Incompatibility of OS with hardware

It might seem funny but I had a very similar issue to your own and it seems that, somehow (by magic), the installation became corrupted and the only fix was to run it again. Therefore, magic.

Comment: Well I ended up getting past it but I would like to cause it as i verified the HASH of the ISO that the install came from, I installed off the same flash drive, but the error only occured on the one system. I've never had it before.  

Unfortunatly I haven't found a solution yet but, what I can say is that by not clicking okay on the error and then continuting the install moving the error off the screen I got it to work...

Comment: This is a very very strange situation. I'm thinking, if you were to open a case with Microsoft, they will drag you thru collecting all the possible logs and end up saying that in this rare problem caused by faulty hardware. For curiosity's sake, if you have time on your hands (I know I'm asking too much), you might want to take a look at the log files. Here's a list of them: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825073.aspx

Comment: LOL. I did actually go through the log files, and found the only possible thing causing it could have been the PAN adapter (bluetooth) however, I can't even say that was it for sure.  I won't have time to go through the logs in more details unfortunately, but if you really need it I can post them somewhere for you.

Comment: So it's hardware incompatibility after all. Sure, post them somewhere and I can have a look. Thanks.